# Why do I need a leading space in this BASH script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, space

Using this script to confirm a macOS Config Profile is installed

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="ApplicationName - Config Profile"
profiles=$(profiles -C -v | awk -F: '/attribute: name/{print $NF}' | grep "$NAME")

if [ "$profiles" == " $NAME" ]; then
    echo "Profile exists"
else
    echo "Profile does not exist"
fi
```

If I don't have the leading space in the conditional (the space before `$NAME`) the conditional is wrong.

```
"$profiles" == "$NAME"
```

This returns "Profile does not exist"

```
"$profiles" == " $NAME"
```

This returns "Profile exists"

I can even `echo $NAME` and `$profiles`, they echo exactly the same, but the if conditional is different depending on that space. Why is this?

Comment: Tangentially, [don't use upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are changing the field separator in the awk command to be a colon, any whitespace will not be considered as a field separator, and so the whitespace will be printed with the `print $NF` statement.  Grep also will not strip the whitespace, so `"$profiles"` really does contain a space at the beginning.  If you put double quotes around `$profiles` when you echo it, you should see that there is a preceding space.  For a `bash` script, it is usually recommended to use double brackets for if statements, e.g. `if [[ $profiles == $NAME ]]; then`  (The double brackets won't solve this problem, but they are safer than single brackets.)

One solution would be to change the grep to another awk invocation:

```
profiles=$(profiles -C -v | awk -F: '/attribute: name/{print $NF}' | awk '/'"$NAME"'/ {$1=$1; print $0}')
```

The above will result in leading whitespace being removed.

Comment: Probably better to fold the two Awk scripts into one, though. `awk -v name="$NAME" -F: '/attribute: name/ && ($NF ~ name) { gsub(/^ +| +$/, "", $NF); print $NF }'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that `profiles` does contain a leading space (have a look at with `echo "'$profiles'"`, which should make the space visible). However, I find the whole logic of your program problematic. You basically want to test, whether the input contains a line `attribute: name ..... $NAME`. In this case, you could do this simply as, i.e.

```
if profiles -C -v|grep -q "attribute: name.*: *$NAME$"
then
  echo Profile $NAME exists
fi
```

This assumes that NAME does not contain characters with special meaning in a regexp. If this can not be guaranteed, you would can write i.e.

```
if profiles -C -v|grep "attribute: name"| grep -Fq "$NAME"
then
  ...
```

This does not catch the requirement that $NAME must be at the end of the line. If this is really important to you (I don't know the possible variety in your input data), you could do the entire matching within awk (and set the exit status accordingly). The point is that for testing the existence of a certain profile name, you don't need to extract that name itself.

**UPDATE**: Incorporating remarks from *tripleee*

Comment: Piping `grep -q` to another `grep` will always fail.

Comment: This loses the requirement that `$NAME` needs to be the last field and preceded by a colon.

Comment: @tripleee : You have a keen eye indee! I would like you doing my code reviews. Will fix it.